# Unable to add components on a new line in this JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'd like to create in Java Swing a file manager-alike interface, with icons spanning horizontally unless no more horizontal space is possible to allocate, and then going to a new line.

This is my current code:

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(156, 36, 1098, 634);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    
    DesktopPanel = new JPanel();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(DesktopPanel);
    DesktopPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
```

So I perform some `DesktopPanel.add(component);` but the components span always horizontally even when there's no more space, so I see the `component`s to go off the screen. I suspect that's because the `FlowLayout` "thinks" there's more space because it's contained in a `JScrollPane` which can have infinite horizontal space, but I do not know how I can confine that space to the visible space only.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a `JList` configured with a `HORIZTONAL_WRAP` as demonstrated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some name are correct, other are not. Be consistent. 2) Don't use setBounds(). It is the job of the layout manager to set the size/location.

Comment: 3) Use the [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) on the "desktopPanel".

Comment: @camickr absolutely correct, that was an oversight, and yes I used WrapLayout and it now works perfectly, thank you!